# How to deal with negative proportions in Dirichlet Regression

Tags: beta-regression, dirichlet-regression

I am trying to work on a Dirichlet regression problem where I look at three true proportions the first two are actually measured while the third is computed as the complement:

$$p_3=1-p_1-p_2$$

The issue that I have is that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are measured with error and hence $p_3$ will sometimes be negative i.e. when $p_1+p_2>1$.

Is there any way to “correct” for this problem? I know there might be a way to do this with a Bayesian approach where you model the measurement error. But I would rather look at a simpler approach such as a proper way to normalise the data.

Comment: Build a hierarchical model where the $p_i$'s are distinguished from their noisy counterparts, the $q_i$'s.

Comment: Since $p_1$ and $p_2$ are measured with error, how do you guarantee that each of them is in the unit interval? If that happens "naturally" then why not compute $p_3$ the "same" way and then normalize the three of them to sum to one?

Comment: Thanks mef, the issue is that I don't have p3. It would be equivalent to measuring a leaf area initially all with healthy tissue and then you have a leaf disease where at a later time you measure (in proportion of the initial area) the proportion of leaf diseased (p1), healthy(p2) and then you have some leaf that disintegrated that you cannot measure. I was trying to avoid having to use a hierarchical model as Xi'an suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Think of $p_3$ as a derived parameter that is not part of the model.  Once you get posterior draws of $(p_{1}, p_{2})$ compute $p_3$ from these draws by subtraction.  Then everything remains consistent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Frank. I am a bit unclear on what you mean. Is the idea to set up the likelihood as: (p_1, p_2,1-p_1-p_2)~Dirichlet treating the  p's as parameters and then have two measurement errors likelihoods for example: y_1~N(p_1,SD)
and y_2~N(p_2,SD)?

Comment: Yes to the first part (I think) and not sure about the second part.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think that by simulating values based on known parameters and retrieving those values would be good enough to be "confident" this approach is sensible?

Comment: This is more about math than about checking algorithm accuracy, but yes it's usually a good idea to simulate form a model and see what data you get.